# Showing that a function is not continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

> The function $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ defined with: 
>   $$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{}
>              1,  &x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
>               0, &x\not\in\mathbb{Q}
>              \end{array}\right.$$
>    is not continuous.
>
> Let $c\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(c)=1$. Let a sequence $(c_n)_n$ from $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ which converges to $c$. Then $f(c_n)=0$ so the sequence $(f(c_n))_n$ doesn't converge to $1$. Analogously, for $c\not\in \Bbb Q$ and $f(c)=0$ let $(c_n)_n$ be a sequence from $\Bbb Q$ which converges to $c$. Then $f(c_n)=1$ so the sequence $(f(c_n))_n$ doesn't converge to $0.$

What's the idea behind all this? I don't see how this proves that a function is not continuous. I have the following definition:

> Let $I\subseteq \Bbb R$ be an open interval, $c\in\ I$ and a function $f:I\rightarrow \Bbb R$. The function $f$ is continuous at a point $c$ if and only if
>
> $$(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists \delta>0)(\forall x\in I)((|x-c|<\delta)\Rightarrow(|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon)).$$

Then if we want to prove that a function is not continuous, doesn't it mean we should prove that:

$$(\exists \varepsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x\in I)((|x-c|<\delta)\land(|f(x)-f(c)|\geq \varepsilon))?$$

Comment: This is Dirichlet's function and the discontinuity can be also proven by the Cauchy definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll prove what you are asking, the way you are asking, but only for $c \in \mathbb Q$. For irrationals, a similar argument follows.

You want to find an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\forall \delta > 0$, there is  an $x \in I$, such that $|x-c| < \delta$ but $|f(x)-f(c)| > \epsilon$.

So we will take $\epsilon = \frac 12$.

For any $\delta > 0$, pick an irrational number $x \in (c, c - \delta)$ (we can do this however small $\delta$ is, as long as it is positive). Then, since $x \notin \mathbb Q, f(x) = 0$, so $|f(x)-f(c)| = 1 > \epsilon$ although $|x - c| < \delta$. This shows  discontinuity at $c \in \mathbb Q$.

The is called the *epsilon-delta* definition of continuity, while the definition being used there is called the *sequential* definition of continuity. You can show these are equivalent, but first read them up.

The sequential definition is the following: $f$ is continuous if whenever $x_n$ is a sequence, $x_n \to c$, then $f(x_n) \to f(c)$. ($\to$ means "converges to").

So in this case, you can find an sequence of irrationals $c_n$ converging to $c$, however $f(c_n) = 0$ in that case, but $f(c) = 1$, and clearly the constant sequence $0$ doesn't converge to $1$, which is a contradiction. This is what the author is trying to say.

Hope you have understood. Do reply back.

Comment: Why is $|f(x)-f(c)|=1?$

Comment: @Lewis $x$ is irrational, so $f(x)=0$. In the starting, I assumed $c$ was rational, so $f(c) = 1$, hence $|f(x) - f(c)| = |0-1| = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

It's using the theorem that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$ for all sequences $x_n$ converging to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

It is using the [sequential criterion](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/sequential-criterion-for-the-continuity-of-a-function). And by the way, it proves that $f$ is not continuous at any point. This is a much stronger fact than just being non continuous (this could be proved, for example, by noting that $f(0)=1$ and $f(\sqrt{2})=0$, but $f(x)\neq0.5$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$).